# Try to start my airbyte worker image and it doesn't works

Tags: java, docker, micronaut

I'm trying to deploy airbyte into k8 as a docker image.
and I build it from this compose
https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/blob/master/docker-compose.yaml

Other images are working fine but only worker image that can't start.
It shows error like this.

```
2023-01-27 05:06:47 [1;31mERROR[m i.m.r.Micronaut(handleStartupException):338 - Error starting Micronaut server: Cannot invoke "io.airbyte.config.storage.CloudStorageConfigs.getType()" because the return value of "io.airbyte.config.helpers.LogConfigs.getStorageConfigs()" is null
```

I'm tried to adjust environment variables but it still show the error.
Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found that value of
`io.airbyte.config.helpers.LogConfigs.getStorageConfigs()` is read from `WORKER_LOGS_STORAGE_TYPE`.
So, when I define `WORKER_LOGS_STORAGE_TYPE` variable worker is working now.

Comment: hey where did you find docs for this variable? i would like to know what options for value there are. thanks!